# How do I write unit test aws-sdk-go-v2 dynamodb implementation

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-go

I am still grasping go-interfaces and I can mock the [WaitUntilTableExists](https://godoc.org/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb#DynamoDB.WaitUntilTableExists) func. But unable to mock [PutItemRequest](https://godoc.org/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb#PutItemRequest).

Here's my **main.go** snippet

```
func MyPutItem(d mydata, client dynamodbiface.DynamoDBAPI) error {
    input := &dynamodb.PutItemInput{
        ....
    }
    req := client.PutItemRequest(input)
    result, err := req.Send()
    log.Println(result)
    return err
}
```

**main_test.go** snippet

```
type mockDynamoDBClient struct {
    dynamodbiface.DynamoDBAPI
}

func (m *mockDynamoDBClient) PutItemRequest(input *dynamodb.PutItemInput) dynamodb.PutItemRequest {
    // Most probably this is where I need your help
}

func TestStoreInDynamoDB(t *testing.T) {
    var mockClient = new(mockDynamoDBClient)
    d := mydata{}
    result := DynampDBPutItem(d, mockClient)
    t.Log(result)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faking the SDK like this works:

main_test.go

```
type fakeDynamoDBClient struct {
    dynamodbiface.DynamoDBAPI
}

func (m *fakeDynamoDBClient) GetItemRequest(input *dynamodb.GetItemInput) dynamodb.GetItemRequest {
    return dynamodb.GetItemRequest{
        Request: &aws.Request{
            Data: &dynamodb.GetItemOutput{
                Item: map[string]dynamodb.AttributeValue{
                    "count": dynamodb.AttributeValue{
                        N: aws.String("10"),
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }
}

func (m *fakeDynamoDBClient) PutItemRequest(input *dynamodb.PutItemInput) dynamodb.PutItemRequest {
    return dynamodb.PutItemRequest{
        Request: &aws.Request{
            Data: &dynamodb.PutItemOutput{},
        },
    }
}

func TestUpdateCount(t *testing.T) {
    err := UpdateCount(10, &fakeDynamoDBClient{})
    if err != nil {
        t.Error("Failed to update badge count on dynamodb", err)
    }
}
```

main.go

```
func UpdateCount(count int, client dynamodbiface.DynamoDBAPI) error {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Taking your example, you could do your assertions directly in the mock

```
type mockDynamoDBClient struct {
    t *testing.T
    expected *dynamodb.PutItemInput
    response *dynamodb.PutItemOutput
    dynamodbiface.DynamoDBAPI
}

func (m *mockDynamoDBClient) PutItemRequest(input *dynamodb.PutItemInput) dynamodb.PutItemOutput {
    // some kind of equality check
    if !reflect.DeepEqual(m.expected, input) {
        t.Errorf(...// some error message)
    }
    return m.response
}
```

The main problems with this example are:

`t *testing.T`, `expected *dynamodb.PutItemInput` and response `response *dynamodb.PutItemOutput` all need to be inside the struct which feels messy.

Instead you could use an anonymous function to do this:

```
type mockDynamoDBClient struct {
    f func(input *dynmaodb.PutItemInput) *dynamodb.PutItemOutput
    dynamodbiface.DynamoDBAPI
}

func (m *mockDynamoDBClient) PutItemRequest(input *dynamodb.PutItemInput) dynamodb.PutItemOutput {
    return m.f(input)
}
```

Now in the test code you can make slightly better use of the mock struct:

```
m := &mockDynamoDBClient{
    f: func(input *dynamodb.PutItemInput) *dynamodb.PutItemOutput {
        // assertions on input
        // return mock responses
    }
}
```

**EDIT** based on comment:

You should also consider making your `MyPutItem` function dependent on the smallest interface possible. If you only need access to the `PutItemRequest` method then you can create your own interface for that method and use that in `MyPutItem`

```
type MyDynamoPutter interface {
    func (c *DynamoDB) PutItemRequest(input *PutItemInput) PutItemRequest
}
```

Then in `MyPutItem` you can use your own interface:

```
func MyPutItem(d mydata, client MyDynamoPutter) error {
    input := &dynamodb.PutItemInput{
        ....
    }
    req := client.PutItemRequest(input)
    result, err := req.Send()
    log.Println(result)
    return err
}
```

This reduces the surface area that you need to mock!

Comment: Thanks! But this doesn't work and PutItemRequest is not satisfying the interface (should return dynamodb.PutItemRequest). The examples in <anything>iface is out-dated (copied from old version) and actually there's more to it: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/issues/70